# Check if apps are installed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, info.plist

I am creating an app that should allow the user to check which apps (also belonging to me) are installed.

I have read a [post](https://cromulentlabs.wordpress.com/2016/01/15/explanation-of-canopenurl-changes-in-ios-9/) that explains that the URL scheme of each app has to be declared on `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in order to be able to check if the app is installed or not. The post is relatively old and I was wondering if other solutions currently exist to check if a list of apps are installed on the device. 
I also found an [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1) on the apple website explaining how to update a property-list data.

Is it possible to use this to update `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in `info.plist` and add new URL scheme?

Comment: do you mean to dynamically update your plist to support quering additional apps?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean

Comment: Since all apps are yours your could create a shared user defaults, keychain or Core Data file using an app group and have each app create an entry when it starts

Comment: I don't think that an app could access core data fille or defaults of another app.

Answer (score 0):

The article on apple explains editing plist files but the plist you want to edit is in the app bundle which is read only.

The only way to edit it is to copy it over to the documents directory of you app and but that will not suffice your requirement to add additional url-schemes

For Question1: `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` is the right way to query for installed apps when you already know the url scheme.

Comment: And supposing I do not know the URL scheme, is there any other way to do that? For example ask the user the permission to access the list of all installed apps? (This is possible on android)

Comment: I'm not aware of such an API from Apple